# NullPointerException exception after submitting commandButton(JSF 2.1)

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I am getting NullPointerException when I click on commonButton to submit the page:

```
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletException
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at ca.bc.gov.hlth.template.filter.ProcessFilter.doFilter(ProcessFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.getRenderer(UIComponentBase.java:1402)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:785)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1181)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:933)
at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.components.PartialTraversalViewRootImpl.processDecodes(PartialTraversalViewRootImpl.java:147)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
... 29 more
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>SSD</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>CUSTOM</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.push.jms.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ExceptionHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>errorHost</param-name>
            <param-value>localhost</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>errorPort</param-name>
            <param-value>24444</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JsonSearch</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ca.bc.gov.hlth.swt.map.JsonSearchServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JsonSearch</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ProcessFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ca.bc.gov.hlth.template.filter.ProcessFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>error-page</param-name>
            <param-value>/faces/Error.xhtml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ProcessFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>ca.bc.gov.hlth.swt.util.StartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/Home.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/faces/AccessDenied.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/faces/Error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

This is my faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.1" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">
  <faces-config-extension>
    <facelets-processing>
      <file-extension>.jspx</file-extension>
      <process-as>jspx</process-as>
    </facelets-processing>
  </faces-config-extension>

   <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>Map</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>swtwar.Map</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>Search</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>swtwar.Search</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>Home</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>swtwar.Home</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>LayoutWide</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>swtwar.LayoutWide</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>Tester</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>swtwar.Tester</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
```

Here is the code I use for CommondButton; #{Home.search} returns 'search':
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
<h:commandButton onclick="document.getElementById('form1:procedureFilter').value='';" action="#{Home.search}" value="Select Search Criteria" />
```

Both Home.xhtml and Search.xhtml(home.xhtml --> Search.xhtml) are in the same folder.
I also found that glassfish 3.1 is giving following error:
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
```

Any Help?

Thanks

Harbinder

Update: After some work around I found that I'm actually getting NullPointerException from the ManagedBean:

```
WARNING: #{Home.search}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{Home.search}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at ca.bc.gov.hlth.template.filter.ProcessFilter.doFilter(ProcessFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at swtwar.Home.search(Home.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 37 more

INFO: HP_excptn:javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at ca.bc.gov.hlth.template.filter.ProcessFilter.doFilter(ProcessFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at swtwar.Home.search(Home.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 37 more
```

Here Home.Search is pointing to:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{Search}")
private Search search;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{Tester}")
private Tester tester;

public Home() {
}

public Search getSearch(){
    return this.search;
}

public void setSearch(Search search){
    this.search = search;
}
public String search() {
    if (siteId == null) {
        init();
    }

    tester.testing();
    return "tester";
}
```

And tester is pointing to Tester.xhtml and testing() is a testing procedure of its bean class:

```
    @ManagedBean
    public class Tester implements Serializable
   {
    public Tester(){
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void testing(){
    System.out.println("HP_Tester_Testing.....");
    }
   }
```

Comment: I would put a breakpoint at ca.bc.gov.hlth.template.filter.ProcessFilter.doFilter(ProcessFilter.java:125) and see what is going on...

Comment: Open the inspector or firebug, depending on the browser you are. Is actually the filter you're referencing taking the `form1:procedureFilter` id at client side? Maybe you're referencing an id which does not exist.

Comment: @XtremeBiker..I don't think `id` mismatch in the javascript causes null pointer!!

Comment: somthing in your bean is null when submit

Comment: @mulax you're right I am actually getting NullPointerException from Home' ManagedBean.To the above summary, I've added latest/new exception and the relavent code of respective beans, as am update. Why the bean is giving me ths error, what is going wrong there?

Comment: What's on line 87? How does `init()` look like? Most probably tester is not initialized. Try putting `System.out.println("Tester: "+tester);` before `tester.testing();`.

Comment: swtwar.Home.search(Home.java:87) which is the line 87? if tester.testing () then "tester" is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

For my case (TomEE plus 1.7.2, JSF 2.2, MyFaces 2.1.17 and Eclipse Luna) f:ajax needed a render kit to complete refreshing of the relevant component.

I had this error in my stackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.getRenderer(UIComponentBase.java:1304)
...
```

similar to yours

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.getRenderer(UIComponentBase.java:1402)
...
```

I resolved the issue by adding render kit declaration in faces config and adding relevant libraries to the project. Of course, the libraries might be different for other implementations.

```
<application>
 <default-render-kit-id>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.core</default-render-kit-id>
</application>
```

**trinidad libraries:**

trinidad-api-2.0.1.jar

trinidad-impl-2.0.1.jar